# just store the time without the data of 01.01.1970 in the time variable

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a 6 digits String to Time without the date with SimpleDateFormat but I am getting the date of 01.01.1970 after converting the time. How can I just get the time stored in the time variable without the date?

**Code**

```
String timeString = "004500";
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmmss");
Date time= formater.parse(timeString );
```

Comment: You can not. A Date variable always store the date part

Comment: A `Date` is **lterally** just milliseconds since `01.01.1970 UTC`. There is absolutely no way to do what you want. Use a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).

Comment: A `Date` object is not suitable for storing just a time (hours, minutes, seconds). Use class `java.time.LocalTime` instead.

Comment: @Jesper You should mentioned that this is only available in java8 and higher

Comment: Yes because I am still using jdk 7 :)

Comment: If you're using JDK 7 or older then use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) - or better, upgrade to Java 8. (Java 8 is not that new anymore!).

Answer (score 2):

you can use LocalTime which is what you want. You can parse a standard date like this:

```
String str = "1986-04-08 12:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
LocalTime time - dateTime.toLocalTime();
```

If you only have a time to parse you can use LocalTime.parse() [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

Note that this is only available starting from Java 8. You can also add [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) as a dependency if you are not using Java 8 yet.

Comment: ok i have edited in your suggestion

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear :)

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the ThreeTen-Backport project, and further adapted for Android in the ThreeTenABP project. The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode with the team advising migration to java.time.